# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, widget, singlechildscrollview

i get Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget. problem

I tried to use Column inside SingleChildScrollView but didn't work, I replace it with ListView

here is my code

```
    return Scaffold(
      body: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: pressBack,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
//              height: 0.9* MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: ListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                           moreCoding(),
                     ],
               ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was an Expanded Widget inside the SingleChildScrollView or inside the ListView